# OR operator in PHP regex (including unicode validation)

Tags: php, regex

Thanks to S. Gehrig's answer in the [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961573/utf-8-isalpha-in-php) I've got a regex which works fine and validates a variable based on the Letter property (except Chinese, but that's another topic :):

```
if (preg_match('/^\p{L}+$/u', $input)) {
    // OK
}
```

Unfortunately I can't extend it to support to support numbers respective question/exclamation & co. My experiments included:

```
'/^[\p{L}]|[0-9]|[\n]|[']|[\?]|[\!]|[\.]|[\,]+$/u'
'/^[\p{L}+]|[0-9]|[\n]|[']|[\?]|[\!]|[\.]|[\,]$/u'
'/^[\p{L}+]|[0-9]|[\n]|[']|[\?]|[\!]|[\.]|[\,]$/u'
```

What is the correct regex? Please point me in the right direction.

Many, many thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do with this regex? The title makes no sense.

Comment: Updated, I hope it makes more sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\p{L}+` is already "non-empty string of `\p{L}`'s". `[]` on the other hand indicate "one of", thus depending on your actual requirements, either of this should work:

Any (positive, non-zero) number of the specified characters in sequence:

```
/^[\p{L}0-9\n'?!.,]+$/u
```

Either a sequence of `\p{L}`s or a sequence of mixed `[0-9\n'?!.,]`:

```
/^(\p{L}+|[0-9\n'?!.,]+)$/u
```

Either a sequence of `\p{L}`s or exactly one of `[0-9\n'?!.,]`:

```
/^(\p{L}+|[0-9\n'?!.,])$/u
```

Comment: You can put the \p{L} inside the character class along with the literal characters.

Comment: thanks for the hint. I'm not particularly firm with php's regexes.

Comment: Attention! Your two regular expressions are NOT equivalent. `/^foo|bar$/` is equal to `/(?:^foo)|(?:bar$)/` and `/(?:^foo|bar$)/` but not equal to `/^(?:foo|bar)$/`!

Comment: Tkx a lot David, it's working perfectly fine. Only ' seems a bit strange, because it's not allowed even if I add i.e. with  preg_match("/^[\p{L}0-9 _.\-']+$/u", $value)