# PHP: RegEx vs. ctype_*

Tags: php, regex, localization

several months ago, [you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961573/utf-8-isalpha-in-php) provided a perfect solution for my IsAlpha & co issues. But once again, I ran into issues after upgrading PHP (to version 5.2.9), although the ctype_* functions seem to do their job now:

```
ctype_alpha( $value ) /* VS */ preg_match("/^[\p{L} _.\-]+$/u",    $value)

ctype_alnum( $value ) /* VS */ preg_match("/^[\p{L}0-9 _.\-]+$/u", $value)
```

By issues, I mean that 'GB' or 'blablue' is i.e. correctly identified as alpha by `ctype_alpha()`, but fails with `preg_match("/^[\p{L} _.\-]+$/u", $value)`.

Please let me know if you have any ideas, I ran out of them after some serious googling..

Many, many thanks!

P.S. `LANG`/`LC_CTYPE`/etc is set to `en_US.UTF-8` both on both environments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure PCRE has been compiled with UTF-8 support as well as Unicode property support.

```
if ( ! @preg_match('/^.$/u', 'ñ'))
    echo 'PCRE has not been compiled with UTF-8 support.';

if ( ! @preg_match('/^\pL$/u', 'ñ'))
    echo 'PCRE has not been compiled with Unicode property support.';
```

Checks from [http://github.com/kohana/kohana/blob/master/install.php](https://github.com/kohana/kohana/blob/3.1/master/install.php).

Comment: Actually ctype_alpha() fails on a ñ character whereas the preg_match() works (assuming you have UTF-8 support.)

Answer (score -1):

I had some issue with a regex using unicode metacharacters on a hosting server. Issue in short: it doesn't work.  I didn't investigate on the true cause since it was a temporary server, but you might look into unicode support as your problem seems similar.

Comment: Please let me know if you mean by unicode the locale setting of the  user running Apache/PHP or something else. Many thanks!