# validate if UTF-8 string is alphabetic

Tags: php, string, utf-8, alphabetic

I have some string:

```
$str = 'Xin chào';
$str2 = 'Xin chào 1';
```

In order to check if these two string variables is alphabetic, I've tried with `ctype_alpha`.
However, both of `ctype_alpha($str)` and `ctype_alpha($str2)` are falsy.

Is there any other method that similars to `ctype_alpha` and working great with UTF-8?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961573/utf-8-isalpha-in-php

Answer (score 2):

this should work for you

```
preg_match('/^\p{L}[\p{L} _.-]+$/u', $str);
```

For more Information take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Comment: Why `p{L}[\p{L} _.-]+`? Just `p{L}+` would be enough.